# Is it safe to cut throught a 70mm spruce beam with a Metabo jigsaw?

Tags: wood, powertools

I have this jigsaw: Metabo Ste 90 SCS  (610 watts).

So far, I'm using it to cut 1cm to 2cm thick wood, and it's a great tool.

I know that the right tool to cut this beam would probably be a miter saw, but I don't plan to buy one for just a few cuts.

I am not looking for the accuracy of cuts for this job.

I have seen that there are 10 cm blades, but I'm wondering if this is safe to put long blades on a powerful jigsaw, to cut thick - and possibly wet - wood. Some beams are so wet that their weight is almost twice the weight of dry ones.

So here what I fear could happen:

- violent kickback at some random point
- blade breaking inside the beam
- burning or damaging the motor,

Comment: Probably a better job for a sawzall

Comment: @Steven Interesting tool, I didn't know it. It looks powerful and not very accurate, as requested.

Comment: justified but shouldn't really be "fears" as if it were something scary. it is not like something will explode. I have jigsaw blades break plenty of times. as for burning the motor, that's also a possibility. since it is thick and wet your blade will get gummed up and have a tough time going through the wood. it is likely the blade will heat up and snap before you damage the tool though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problems you mention are possible if you try to advance the jigsaw too aggressively and even with thinner materials. Just don't advance it too fast and especially don't force on the jigsaw and it'll be fine although rather slow.

The other side is that those 10cm blades are rather expensive and you might be much better off just using a handsaw for the few cuts you need.

Comment: OK I'll have a try, do it slowly and let the jigsaw do its work. I cut one with a handsaw, but it was so wet that the blade could barely move after ~ 2 cm , and I had to reiterate the cut on each side.

Comment: @Antoine: The problem is likely with the wet chips getting stuck inside the cut - you could pause cutting, retrieve the jigsaw, then put it back and continue - that should help remove the wet chips.

Comment: I must say I underestimated a lot the power of this Metabo jigsaw. I bought a 10 cm blade (~5€) and with the right settings, I almost didn't realize that I was cutting through the beam.

Answer (score 1):

For goodness sake - use a handsaw!

And if it sticks a little rub some candle wax on the blade.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, I have been using 610w jigsaw to make 60mm deep cuts, just  go slowly, and make sure blade is perpendicular to the wood.